# Stop program flow in Qt without using sleep

Tags: qt

Below is the code I am working on. For now what happens is, even though I am creating an object `ImageCropper *newwindow = new ImageCropper();`(from the give code below), the code which comes after the object creation are being executed even before the code in the constructor and related functions are completed.

So the problem is, I am setting a few variables in the constructor(I am again calling a function from this constructor which is setting the variables). In the function below when I am trying to access the variables like this: `newwindow->x2` it is showing junk/random number instead of the values which are being set in the other class. So how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->pushButton->setDisabled(true);
ui->pushButton_2->setDisabled(false);

    ImageCropper *newwindow = new ImageCropper();
    this->hide();

    newwindow->setWindowOpacity(.1);
    newwindow->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    newwindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    newwindow->showFullScreen();

    originalPixmap = QPixmap(0,0);
    screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0, newwindow->x2, newwindow->y2, newwindow->w2, newwindow->h2);
    qDebug()<<"x:"<<newwindow->x2<<" | "<<"y:"<<newwindow->y2<<" | "<<"h:"<<newwindow->h2<<" | "<<"w:"<<newwindow->w2;

    connect(newwindow,SIGNAL(destroyed()),this,SLOT(show()));

}
```

Comment: Are you implying that `this->hide();` is executed before entire code from constructor of `ImageCropper()` was executed?

Comment: `originalPixmap = screen->grabWindow(0, newwindow->x2, newwindow->y2, newwindow->w2, newwindow->h2);`

These executed before `imageCropper()` got executed.

Comment: This is not possible. A single thread in C++ executes instructions one by one and will not start next instruction, until first one is not finished. Have you tried to debug it? Use debugger, or even put `qDebug()` statements throughout this entire method and observe how it's executed.

Comment: I tried `qDebug()` in the `ImageCropper()` constructor function and it is actually giving the right values. I think it is happening because this is using events and all the values are being set in: `void ImageCropper::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)`

Comment: Even the mouse release event would occur, it would not be passed to `ImageCropper` yet, because your application is busy executing rest of the `on_pushButton_clicked()` and the main event loop doesn't have a chance to process its events yet. Qt GUI is always a single thread, so there's no way any GUI event is processed paralelly. Try more with `qDebug()` to find out what is really happening.